# Пошаговая работа представленного кода JS

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет!
Помогите разобраться как работает представленный ниже код.
Желательно по пунктам, шаг за шагом.
Не могу уловить суть повторения цикла, как осуществляется переход к следующей итерации?
Ведь если условие `if (foundPos == -1)` выполняется, то мы прерываем цикл директивой `break` и переходим за тело цикла, а там пустота. Как осуществляется итерация ?

```
let str = 'Ослик Иа-Иа посмотрел на виадук';

let target = 'Иа'; // цель поиска
let pos = 0;

while (true) {
  let foundPos = str.indexOf(target, pos);
  if (foundPos == -1) break;

  alert( `Найдено тут: ${foundPos}` );
  pos = foundPos + 1; // продолжаем со следующей позиции
}
```

Comment: Так тут всё правильно, когда найдены все цели нужно прерывать цикл. (`indexOf` возвращает -1 если не нашёл ничего по запросу)

Comment: чтобы пошагово посмотреть что где - надо воспользоваться отладкой

Comment: @ΝNL993 так я понимаю, что код корректно работает. Вопрос в логике его исполнения, не могу понять как он повторяется. Ведь если мы при первом использовании метода `str.indexOf(target, pos);` передаем туда искомую подстроку `'Иа'` и `pos 0`, то метод возвращает -1 (совпадение не найдено). Тогда должен сразу `if == true` и выполняется инструкция `break`, соответственно цикл сразу прерывается, но этого не происходит.

Comment: str.indexOf(substr, pos)  ищет подстроку substr в строке str, начиная с позиции pos, заканчивая концом строки str, и возвращает позицию, на которой располагается совпадение, либо -1 при отсутствии совпадений. Почему же он должен вернуть -1, если искомая подстрока в наличии?

Comment: @GlebProkhorov В смысле не происходит? Поставьте `console.log('iteration')` после проверки if и до `alert`, по идее в консоли должно быть два сообщения 'iteration', а если там появилось больше двух сообщений соответственно - цикл не прервался.

Comment: @AndreySemykin спасибо! Внимательно прочитал еще раз, по вашей наводке, как работает данный метод `str.indexOf(substr, pos)` и все встало на свои места. Благодарю за простой, но содержательный ответ.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Благодарю, попробовал и ваш подход. Разобрался, спасибо!